# Windows server 2016 can't connect to remote port other than 80

Tags: windows, firewall, http

I have a remote linux server running an HTTP service on a port 5000. I can use this service from my personal Windows computer with no problem, even connecting other remote servers is OK. However, my Windows server 2016 cannot connect to this service, it always times out.

When I switched the service to run only on port 80, even Windows server 2016 was able to connect. I tried adding rules to this Windows server 2016 firewall, inbound and outbound port rules, but nothing worked. I am sure it's only something related to firewall configuration, but I can't figure out what. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Not sure if you already do this but it is worth mentioning that you should add `http://` in front of the URL when the port is not `80`. So the URL should be `http://x.x.x.x:5000`

Comment: Already tried that, thanks for suggestion but it did not help